# Watch All emails Through Gsuite Account

Tags: google-api, gmail, webhooks, google-workspace

I'm familiar with the concepts of [push notification with Gmail](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) and 'webhooks' in general.
My question is - is there a way to get push notifications about **all** Gmail Users Emails that are related to the same **Gsuite** Account?
I know that there is a way to get global token by 
[Perform G Suite Domain-Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation)
but I can't find enough info about how to listen to all user's emails and if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail API uses the Cloud Pub/Sub API to deliver [push notifications](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push). This allows notification via a variety of methods including webhooks and polling on a single subscription endpoint.

```
POST "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/watch"
Content-type: application/json

{
  topicName: "projects/myproject/topics/mytopic",
  labelIds: ["INBOX"],
}
```

Info on how to [implement domain wide dedication](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

Comment: it seems that this require each user in the Gsuite account to approve my App and its scope permissions , and only after that i will be able to send a Watch request for each user in order to listen to his email changes.

my purpose is to get [wide-access from the administrator][1] in order to get notifications about all the users emails, by once

[1]: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation

Comment: You should be able to create a service account and have the admin grant it domain wide permissions.

Comment: but will i be able to create a single Watch request that create push notification for all the users? 
because i need to send the userId/'me' parameter so it seems not possible